# How to enable HSTS on IIS7 with .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: iis-7, hsts

When I try to use this configuration in my `web.config` file:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.domain.co.uk/"
              httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

I got this error when browsing the web app:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

How do I fix this?

Comment: There's probably more to that error message than what you've posted. Can you take a screenshot and upload?

Comment: Also, I'm not seeing how you're enabling HSTS anywhere in that configuration.

Comment: See also: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEnableHTTPStrictTransportSecurityHSTSInIIS7.aspx which links to this answer which is apparently the correct way to implement HSTS on IIS7+: http://serverfault.com/questions/417173/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-in-iis-7/629594#629594